# Select a specific id and post only that

Tags: php, mysql, post

> $sql = 'SELECT * FROM artikel ORDER BY at_kategori ';
>
> ```
> - id
> - overskrift
> - besked
> - at_kategori [1 - 3]
> ```

So right now it post everyone of at_kategori, but i want it to only post what has the number 1 in at_kategori and not the rest

Comment: Could you explain what exactly you want ? Its really not clear from the question.

Comment: `select * from artikel where at_kategori = 1`.

Comment: Sorry i didn't explain more. But you did help me now. It was because i only wanted to post what i have in my database that has the number  1    in   at_kategori

Comment: Provide some sample data into the question and the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select * from artikel where at_kategori = 1